# "Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object" Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php:180

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I wrote my custom middleware, but when it is executed, the error appears.
Middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Employee;

class CheckConfirm
{
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(Auth::check())          
    {
        $id = Auth::id();        
        $empl = Employee::where('user_id','=', $id)->get();
        if($empl->isEmpty())
        {
            return route('confirm');                    
        }
        else
        {                
            dump($empl);
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return route('login');
    }
}
}
```

When I try something like this:

```
if($empl===null)
   {
      return route('confirm');                    
   }
```

сondition just doesn't work.
In this case, database queries are executed successfully.
[Here is the error page with dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlfzS.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your middleware must return a `Response` object, or `$next($request)`. As written, when not logged in or when `$empl` is empty, your middleware is just returning a string, not a redirect.

Update your returns to:

```
return redirect()->route('confirm');
```

and

```
return redirect()->route('login');
```

respectively.

Comment: Thaks for help, but my project is finally broken) When I try to login or register, it's try to redirect me on correct url, but immediately returns to login.

Comment: @VladislavFinder If you're having more issues, you'll need to post a new question with updated code and the new issue you're having.

Comment: Depending on how are you setting your routes' middlewares, the authentication POST will also (or not) evaluate this middleware you wrote prior to make the actual login, so it will never authenticate the user.

Answer (score 1):

It is very hard to fix, I tried to do it with App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::except, but not work.

My solution to this problem was creating a redirect to another route using App\Exception\Handler::render method.

```
if ($exception->getMessage() == "Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object") {
  return redirect()->route('my.default.page');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
$empl = Employee::where('user_id','=', $id)->get();
        if($empl->isEmpty()){ ... }
```

With this:

```
$empl = Employee::where('user_id', $id)->first();
        if($empl){ ... }
```

Then dd() for each line, see where it fails. There may be an missing csrf token or the user is not logged..

Comment: thanks for help. The user is autorized, because there is an external condition: `if(Auth::check())` . When I used  `first()` I got a new error: 'Call to a member function isEmpty() on null'

Comment: remove isEmpty() you don't need it when fetching single user

Comment: when I use this condition: 
`if($empl)
            {
                return route('confirm');                    
            }
` 
then nothing happens,  but I used `dump($empl)` and it showed me that variable is null, but when I try this: 
`if($empl == null)
            {
                return route('confirm');
            }
`
I get the same error that I complained about at the beginning.